# How to get the default button color in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'd like to change default MenuButton style. I want to use the default button color instead of `Color.gray`

```
MenuButton("Actions") {
    Button(action: {
    }, label: { Text("Action 1") })
    Button(action: {
    }, label: { Text("Action 2") })
}
.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).foregroundColor(Color.gray))
```

I try to change the default style that looks like
[image]

to the style like button
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to get, but probably something like `Color(NSColor.controlColor))` or from that area would help you.

Comment: Thanks, you your solution is good. I added more info about my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am using it like this:

```
        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
```

Created Style like this:

```
struct MainButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    let minWidth: CGFloat
    let minHeight: CGFloat
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        Button(configuration)
            .frame(minWidth: minWidth, minHeight: minHeight)
            .font(.body)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
    Button(action: { }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "map")
    })
    .buttonStyle(MainButtonStyle(minWidth: 30, minHeight: 30))
```