# Set a property to its default value explicitly in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click Me") {
            isRed.toggle()
        }
        .foregroundColor(isRed ? .red : /* some code */)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to apply the following logic:

If `isRed` is `true` then apply the color red, else revert back to the default value for this property or the inherited value if there is one.

In other words are there keywords in SwiftUI similar to `initial` and `inherit` in CSS?

Comment: try `nil`, if that's what you are looking.

Comment: In know it is not SwiftUI but it could be a solution... Try Color(NSColor.controlColor)) (see here) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224426/how-to-get-the-default-button-color-in-swiftui]

Comment: "default value", do you mean `.primaryColor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments many APIs accept `nil` for *default / no change*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click Me") {
            isRed.toggle()
        }
        .foregroundColor(isRed ? .red : nil)
    }
}
```

This works even if you specify a different tint color

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click Me") {
            isRed.toggle()
        }
        .foregroundColor(isRed ? .red : nil)
        .tint(.yellow)
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default color for the buttons is the "accent color". You can use it in the modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRed = false

    Button("Click Me") {
        isRed.toggle()
    }
    .foregroundColor(isRed ? .red : .accentColor)
}
```